For every $0 \leq a <1$, there is a rare measurable set $E \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $m(E)\geq a$.
For every $0 \leq a <1$, there is a rare measurable set $E \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $m(E)\geq a$.
Note: A rare subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is called rare if its closure has empty interior.
Does such set $E$ exist? Why or why not?
Thanks for your help!

Are nowhere-dense sets rare? If so, yes.

The example in the answer below is probably the simplest. An alternative class of sets which may satisfy this property are generalized Cantor sets, see a formula for their measure on page 39 of Folland’s Real analysis.

Yes, such a set $E$ exists, as we show below.
Take a countable dense set subset of $[0,1]$, for instance, $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, and enumerate it $q_1, q_2, \dots$. Define an open ball $B_i = B\left(q_i, \frac{(1-a)}{2^{i+1}}\right)$ of radius $\frac{(1-a)}{2^{i+1}}$ centred at $q_i$. Now $E:= [0,1]\backslash \cup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$ is closed since its complement $\cup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$ is a union of open sets, and $E$ is nowhere dense (aka rare), since any set with non-empty interior in $[0,1]$ contains a rational, and by construction $E$ does not. Finally, we have $m(E)\geq 1-(1-a)\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i}} = a$, as desired.

You wrote: "..., since any dense set in $[0,1]$ contains a rational".  It is not true. I think you meant: "..., since any open set in $[0,1]$ contains a rational".

Yes good catch. I meant any set with non-empty interior. Edited now.

This is similar to Mathieu Rundström's answer but a little more constructive.
Choose some positive real $k$ and consider the following countable union of intervals around all the dyadic fractions of the form $n/2^m$ between $0$ and $1$:
$$U_k = \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{2^m-1} \left[\frac{n}{2^m}-\frac{k}{2^{2m}}, \frac{n}{2^m}+\frac{k}{2^{2m}}\right]$$
You have $m(U_k) \le  \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2^m-1} \frac{2k}{2^{2m}} =k\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(2^m-1)}{2^{2m-1}} =\frac43k$ and in fact strictly less than $k$ as many of the intervals overlap: for example $\left[\frac24-\frac k{16}, \frac24+\frac k{16}\right] \subset \left[\frac12-\frac k4, \frac12+\frac k4\right]$.
So if you say $$E_k = \big[0,1\big] \,\backslash \,U_k$$ then

Any neighbourhood of any point in $\operatorname{cl} E_k$ contains an interval of positive length from the construction of $U_k$ - in fact an infinite number of such excluded intervals - and so the interior of $\operatorname{cl} E_k$ is empty.

$m(E_k) =1 - m(U_k) \ge 1-\frac43k$, so for any  $a \in [0,1)$ you can choose $k < \frac34(1-a)$  to create  an $E_k$ with $m(E_k)>a$ as required.


Here is a chart of $m(E_k)$ plotted against $k$ that I drew almost two decades ago.

